# How to upload an object (hashMap with image and other data) into Firebase Realtime Database and Firebase Storage without internet connection?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let me explain my situation. I have an Activity in Android Studio where I fill some stuff like; names, descriptions,... and an image. The data goes to the Firebase Realtime Database with the image reference from the Firebase Storage as well like this:

```
                HashMap boulderHash = new HashMap();
                boulderHash.put("boulderkey", latlong);
                boulderHash.put("userid", currentUserID);
                boulderHash.put("username", dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString());
                boulderHash.put("profileimage", downloadURL2);
                ...

                final HashMap boulderImageHash = new HashMap();
                boulderImageHash.put("images", downloadURL1);
                boulderImageHash.put("profilestorage", storage);
                boulderImageHash.put("counter", counter);
                boulderImageHash.put("userid", currentUserID);

                    BoulderRef.child(latlong).updateChildren(boulderHash).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {


                                DatabaseReference key = BoulderRef.child(finalLatlong).child("BoulderImages").push();
                                imageKey = key.getKey();

                                BoulderRef.child(finalLatlong).child("BoulderImages").child(imageKey).updateChildren(boulderImageHash
```

All this happens when I click a button and if I have no internet connection I use the **FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);** so the operation is waiting for connection to upload this. Everything is fine with this 'cause if I don't close the app eventually my phone gets the connection back and it uploads the data.

The problem comes when I close the app from the background, is there any option to save this data or the operation into localstorage or cache and automatically send this like it does without closing the app?

Comment: You say, *The problem comes when I close the app from the background*, so what is that problem?

Comment: @AlexMamo my app is about uploading climbing places so many of the users want to upload them when they are in the mountain without internet so if they accidentally close the app before they get connection the places will not be uploaded. That’s what I want to avoid.